# Is CRF suitable for multi-words Named Entity Recognition?

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I've a problem where I should create a custom NER by using [sklearn CRF](https://sklearn-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html). In the official tutorial, they are using CoNLL2002 corpus is available in NLTK where the entities are represented with a single word but in my problem, an entity can be formed with multiple words ex: United States of America, Cinema at Miami, etc.

Can CRF handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. If you look at the [training tutorial](https://sklearn-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#training), it implies that this isn't an issue at all. When using multi-word entities, you typically need to use a [IOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside%E2%80%93outside%E2%80%93beginning_(tagging)) or BILUO tagging schemes, which helps your model train better.

But from a mathematical perspective, there aren't any restrictions for a CRF, as CRF models the likelihood of particular sequences/transitions. Often, people set restrictions for particular transitions if you know in advance that they aren't possible. But by default, all transitions are allowed. In sklearn-crf, allowing all transitions is done by using the `all_possible_transitions=True` argument.